# Reusable select's behaviour in angular while charging its options via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, code-reuse

I know this is maybe too general question but i would like to know how to make a reusable select (or any input) that when i am wating for its options (by an ajax request) it shows a 'Charging ...' message as the selected option.

So for example in any of my views i can use a directive called 'ajax-charged' and every select with that directive would have that behaviour.

The Html i imagine while charging:

```
<select ng-options="opt in options" ajax-charged>
<option>Charging ... </option>
</select>
```

The charged html:

```
<select ng-options="opt in options" ajax-charged>
<option>opt1</option>
<option>opt2</option>
<option>etc</option>
</select>
```

I thought in changing the options to an array with just a 'Charging ...' item, but how to do it reusable? Any other approach will be welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

Your directive would need to know which array it's watching. You can pass it into the directive, and have the the directive watch this array.

I created a fiddle showing this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/TMVFN/1/

HTML:

```
  </select>
  <select ng-model="selectedA" ng-options="optA for optA in optionsA" ajax-charged="optionsA">

  </select>

{{selectedA}}, {{selectedB}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.optionsA = ['opt1', 'opt2', 'etc'];
        $scope.optionsB = ['opt4', 'opt5'];
    }, 3000);
    $scope.optionsB = ['opt3'];
    $scope.selectedB = 'opt3';
};

myApp.directive('ajaxCharged', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {            
            $scope.$watch(attrs.ajaxCharged, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log(newVal);
                if (typeof(newVal) === 'undefined' ||
                    typeof(newVal.length) === 'undefined' || 
                    newVal.length === 0) {
                    $scope[attrs.ajaxCharged] = ['Charging...'];
                } else if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.length > 0) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(newVal[0]);
                }
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```